# I using WebView for background of Activity. but soft key is not work correctly

Tags: android, css, android-layout, svg, webview

I want to use animation file, type of SVG, in background of Activity.

(I use this Activity for Login page)

So, I uploaded an web-page made by CSS and JS file on server.

Then I made an Activity's layout.

Layout Structure is same with next.

FrameLayout(the most highest parent's Layout) - WebView(width, height = match_parent) - RelativeLayout(He has Image for Logo) - LinearLayout(He has many Views, textview and EditText).

As a result, animation page loaded well, but soft key is not work correctly.

On EditText for input Id and Pw, backspace key is not working well.

EditText(password type) backspace key is perfectly not work. (It's input type is password)

Specifically, on Environment of Emulator, it is work well.

But on Environment of real devices, it is caused the matter.

I don't know why it is do that.

below is my codes. thanks for reading.

it is webView layout code

```
<!--Layout xml File, part webView-->
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/loginBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    >
```

below is layout of editText (id, pw)

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/inputPW"
                                android:layout_width="240dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="25sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/inputId"
                                android:layout_width="250dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"

                                android:textSize="25sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
```

it is java codes for webviews

```
loginBackground = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loginBackground);
    loginBackground.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = loginBackground.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    loginBackground.loadUrl("~~~~~URL PATH~~~~");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take `EditText` replace of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`.Your problem will be solved out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. This problem caused by wrapping another Layout to WebView.
below is my solution.

1. make two Activities. A activity is filled up WebView, then set background of another activity to Transparency.

(I will call that WebView activity is A, another activity is B)

2. Invoke A, then invoke B in Activity A.
3. As a result, you will see Activities both on one screen, but you can use independently.
4. If you want to finish activities both on same moment, you can overwrite 'OnBackPressed' method. you must remove object of activity A on activity stack . You can remove that to use static variable or flag.

Thanks for your reading, and I hope to help your project.